# Is there a way to stop Google Chrome from saving passwords into Gnome Keyring?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, gnome-keyring

I have lots of passwords in Chrome which are stored within the Gnome Keyring. Is there an way to stop Chrome from doing that? My keyring file is very large by now and full with web passwords, i dont want them there.

gnome-keyring-demon is on 100% cpu all the time, i need the keyring for important passwords, like ftp, ssh and so on, but i seriously do not need all the web stuff in there.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1174162/comments/28

Comment: if you remove those files you loose all passwords.

Comment: Yep, as the next comment says.

Comment: This by the way does not stop Chrome from saving passowrds there.